# Xbox One on 1440x900 monitor

Tags: xbox-one, monitor, hdmi

I am running my xbone on a 1440x900 monitor with an HDMI to DVI cable (monitor link: http://static.highspeedbackbone.net/pdf/Gateway_FPD1975W_Manual.pdf).

My Playstation 3 is able to output 1080p to this monitor (with the same cable, if that matters). I think the monitor downscales the PS3 output automatically. However, the xbone will only output 480p when connected to this monitor. I don't understand why the PS3 will output 1080p to this monitor, but the xbone will not. I've tried resetting the xbone display output, but it still outputs at 480p. Does anybody know of a way to force the xbone to output 1080p or something? I can't think that it's a problem with the monitor considering it will automatically downscale the PS3 output properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so my problem ended up being that I just wasn't digging deep enough in the display settings on the xbox. Since the 1440x900 monitor I'm using is connected with DVI, I needed to go into Settings > General > TV & Display options > Video fidelity & overscan > Overrides. From there, I selected DVI. After that, I was able to select 1080p from General > TV & display options > Resolution.